# How can I get the page orientation of a PDF page?

Tags: perl, pdf

The function getPageDimensions (of CAM::PDF) returns same values for both portrait and landscape pages.
How can I identify the orientation of a PDF page?
I am using CAM::PDF Perl library and would like to know how to do this using this library.
But any other means to identify this is also welcome (preferably using a Perl lib).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of CAM::PDF.

Well, there's two parts to this.  One is the page's dimensions, as you noted. That works as expected: I used Apple's Preview.app to rotate a PDF file and ran these two command lines:

```
perl -MCAM::PDF -le'print "@{[CAM::PDF->new(shift)->getPageDimensions(1)]}"' orig.pdf 
0 0 612 792
perl -MCAM::PDF -le'print "@{[CAM::PDF->new(shift)->getPageDimensions(1)]}"' rotated.pdf 
0 0 792 612
```

But there's also the `/Rotate' page attribute.  The argument is a number of degrees (default 0, but 90 or 270 are not uncommon).  Like page dimensions, it's an inheritable property so you have to navigate to parent pages.  Here's a quick-and-dirty command line tool to output the rotation value:

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $filename = shift || die;
my $pagenum = shift || die;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename) || die;
my $pagedict = $pdf->getPage($pagenum);
my $rotate = 0;
while ($pagedict) {
   $rotate = $pdf->getValue($pagedict->{Rotate});
   if (defined $rotate) {
      last;
   }
   my $parent = $pagedict->{Parent};
   $pagedict = $parent && $pdf->getValue($parent);
}
print "/Rotate $rotate\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.
I figured that $pagedict->{Rotate}->{value} part.
But not parent part.
Thanks again.

Comment: Small correction.

"my $rotate" inside the while should be $rotate.

Comment: Thanks. My test PDF had an explicit "/Rotate 0" (not sure why...) so I didn't notice the bug.