# How do I get text orientation of a text string in a PDF page using CAM::PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf

I am using CAM::PDF and I want to find out how to get the orientation of a text string.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by orientation?

Comment: Orientation = vertical or horizontal (or maybe any other angle like 180 or 270)

Comment: Horizontal should be 0 degrees and Vertical should be 90.

Comment: This string, is this something you read out from any arbitrary PDF input file? Perhaps you could describe your use case a little more in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat related questions: [How can I get the page orientation of a PDF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662602/how-can-i-get-the-page-orientation-of-a-pdf-page) and [How do I get character offset information from a pdf document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196788/how-do-i-get-character-offset-information-from-a-pdf-document)

Starting with the solution for the latter question, I came up with this recipe:

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('my.pdf') or die $CAM::PDF::errstr;
for my $pagenum (1 .. $pdf->numPages) {
   my $pagetree = $pdf->getPageContentTree($pagenum) or next;
   my @text = $pagetree->traverse('MyRenderer')->getTextBlocks;
   for my $textblock (@text) {
      print "text '$textblock->{str}' at ",
      "($textblock->{left},$textblock->{bottom}), angle $textblock->{angle}\n";
   }
}

package MyRenderer;
use base 'CAM::PDF::GS';

sub new {
   my ($pkg, @args) = @_;
   my $self = $pkg->SUPER::new(@args);
   $self->{refs}->{text} = [];
   return $self;
}
sub getTextBlocks {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return @{$self->{refs}->{text}};
}
sub renderText {
   my ($self, $string, $width) = @_;
   my ($x, $y) = $self->textToDevice(0,0);
   my ($x1, $y1) = $self->textToDevice(1,0);
   push @{$self->{refs}->{text}}, {
      str => $string,
      left => $x,
      bottom => $y,
      angle => atan2($y1-$y, $x1-$x),
   };
   return;
}
```

which yielded this result for page 565 of PDFReference15_v5.pdf:

```
text 'ab' at (371.324,583.7249), angle -1.5707963267949
text 'c' at (371.324,576.63365), angle -1.5707963267949
```

Note that the angle is in radians.  Divide by Pi and multiply by 180 to convert that to degrees.  So, -1.5707963267949 is 270 degrees, which agrees with page 565.

Note that the angle printed is the angle relative to the page content. If the page itself is further rotated (as per the page orientation question above) then you may want to compound the rotation calculations.

Comment: Screenshot of page 565 of that PDF, showing the rotated text: http://chrisdolan.net/misc/page-orientation-example.png

Comment: Thanks Chris!
Worked like a charm.
In fact, I posted one of the related questions you referred to.
And I was hoping that you'll answer this one as well.
Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, so you did!  Funny, I thought your name looked familiar, but I didn't place it. :-)