# Can I get the page size and page orientation using PDF::API2?

Tags: perl, pdf

I can't see any way to get the page size (A4, US Letter, A3 etc) or the page orientation (portrait or landscape) using
[`PDF::API2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2).

Are there any ways to get this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the page orientation of a PDF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662602/how-can-i-get-the-page-orientation-of-a-pdf-page)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
$page->get_mediabox
```

The result is two *x,y* coordinates which will also define the orientation

Comment: my ($llx, $lly, $x, $y) = $page->get_mediabox();

Comment: What are the llx and lly values?